# MEF: Get list of successfully loaded plugin files and exported types

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, mef

I'm using pretty standard MEF to load plugins in from a directory:

```
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(this.GetType().Assembly));

        this.directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(pluginDirectory);
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);

        this.container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        try
        {
            this.container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
        catch (CompositionException compositionException)
        {
            log.Error(compositionException);
            throw;
        }
        catch (System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException rtle)
        {
            foreach (var e in rtle.LoaderExceptions)
                log.Error(e);
        }
```

In my plugin directory I have the plugins as well as other .dll files that do not expose the `IPlugin` interface.

I want to get the list of successfully loaded `IPlugin` implementations as well as from which files they originated.

I've tried looking at `directoryCatalog.LoadedFiles`, but that just lists the files in the directory, whether they are actual plugins or otherwise.

I've looked at the export definitions, but that gives me no clue about the origin file of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can check loaded plugins this way:

`[ImportMany(typeof(IPlugin))]
  public IEnumerable<IPlugin> _plugins;`

`Plugin`'s realizations should be marked as `[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]`. After that you will have loaded plugins in `_plugins` variable